# Spring Data: Parent's id is not being set for OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Code is very simple:

```
//parent class
public class LinkedInProfile {
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "linkedInProfile", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    protected Set<Contact> contacts;
}

//child class
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "profile_id")
    protected LinkedInProfile linkedInProfile;
```

Error I get:

```
Hibernate: insert into child_table (profile_id, type, value) values (?, ?, ?)
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: null value in column "profile_id" violates not-null constraint
```

Rest implementation:

```
public LinkedInProfile save( @RequestBody LinkedInProfile profile) {
return linkedInProfileDao.save(profile);
}
```

Dao implementations:

```
@Repository
public interface LinkedInProfileDao extends JpaRepository<LinkedInProfile, Long> {

}
public interface ChildDao extends JpaRepository<Child, Long> {

}
```

Why the parent id is being set to null?

Comment: and how are you setting the parent profile id in child entity?

Comment: I am not setting it explicitely. Wouldn't `JpaRespository.save` will take care of it?

Comment: so you are not associating any profile parent with your child? i will suggest to start there and set the link. JpaRepoistory.save will ensure referential integrity in database .

Comment: @Sanj Updated my implementation code. How would I make explicit association?

Comment: set the profile in child entity - child.setLinkedInProfile

Comment: @Sanj How would I do that? Sorry not getting what you are saying. Add a setter in child class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108120/discussion-between-sanj-and-himanshu-yadav).